# The near-close, near-front unrounded vowel symbol

Tags: fonts, linguistics, tipa

I'm trying to get the [near-close near-front unrounded vowel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-close_near-front_unrounded_vowel) symbol into LaTeX (in the context of a dictionary-style definition). It looks like " i " but without the dot.

The closest I've got is `\textsc{i}`, which as you probably know is not right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [tipa](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tipa) package for phonetic symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
\textipa{I}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want an `i` without the dot, use `\i`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\i
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Search for its [unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/026a/index.htm), check the [fonts](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/026a/fontsupport.htm) which support it (or [look](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%C9%AA%20-%20LATIN%20LETTER%20SMALL%20CAPITAL%20I%20%28U%2B026A%29), if it already exists on your machine), and include it with `\symbol{}` of the package [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec).

This requires Xe- or LuaLaTeX:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}    
    \symbol{"026A}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Shaun, you can use this solution without needing to use `\symbol` if you have a Unicode-enabled TeX editor (most are these days). You can just input ɪ directly in the editor, using an [IPA keyboard](http://scripts.sil.org/UniIPAKeyboard) or copy-and-pasting from an online IPA picker. This way you can easily write something like /ðɪs ɪz ə sɛntɨnts/ without using any LaTeX commands.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for `\textsci` in the `tipa` package.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
I \textsc{i} \textsci
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ``\textsci`` is the same as ``\textipa{I}``. The ``tipa`` package defines (all?) symbols in two ways: (1) Using shortcut characters in IPA environments (``\textipa{...}``), (2) Using longer macros in text environments (e.g. ``\textsci``).